# ffmpeg link error with CodeBlocks

Tags: c, ffmpeg, static-libraries, codeblocks

Hi，I am currently doing a real time video encoding c program using ffmpeg, initially I encountered a lot of "undefined reference" error, after I set the linker in build options, some error got disappeared, but still some error remains.

```
||=== Build: Debug in c_3rd party encoding (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)     ===|
/home/yonghao/codeblocksfile/c_3rd party encoding/main.c||In function     ‘init_video_encode’:|
/home/yonghao/codeblocksfile/c_3rd party encoding/main.c|73|warning: ‘avcodec_alloc_frame’ is deprecated (declared at ../../ffmpeg_build/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3618) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
/home/yonghao/codeblocksfile/c_3rd party encoding/main.c||In function ‘cancle_encode’:|
/home/yonghao/codeblocksfile/c_3rd party encoding/main.c|134|warning: ‘avcodec_free_frame’ is deprecated (declared at ../../ffmpeg_build/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3643) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
/home/yonghao/codeblocksfile/c_3rd party encoding/main.c|21|warning: ‘endcode’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
../../ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)||In function `mp3lame_encode_frame':|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|211|undefined reference to `lame_encode_buffer_float'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|195|undefined reference to `lame_encode_buffer'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|198|undefined reference to `lame_encode_buffer_int'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|219|undefined reference to `lame_encode_flush'|
../../ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)||In function `mp3lame_encode_close':|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|86|undefined reference to `lame_close'|
../../ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o)||In function `mp3lame_encode_init':|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|98|undefined reference to `lame_init'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|102|undefined reference to `lame_set_num_channels'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|103|undefined reference to `lame_set_mode'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|106|undefined reference to `lame_set_in_samplerate'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|107|undefined reference to `lame_set_out_samplerate'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|111|undefined reference to `lame_set_quality'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|115|undefined reference to `lame_set_VBR'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|116|undefined reference to `lame_set_VBR_quality'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|120|undefined reference to `lame_set_VBR'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|121|undefined reference to `lame_set_VBR_mean_bitrate_kbps'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|123|undefined reference to `lame_set_brate'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|128|undefined reference to `lame_set_bWriteVbrTag'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|131|undefined reference to `lame_set_disable_reservoir'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|134|undefined reference to `lame_init_params'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|140|undefined reference to `lame_get_encoder_delay'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c|143|undefined reference to `lame_get_framesize'|
../../ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libopusdec.o)||In function `libopus_flush':|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c|178|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decoder_ctl'|
../../ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libopusdec.o)||In function `libopus_decode':|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c|143|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decode_float'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c|139|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decode'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c|148|undefined reference to `opus_strerror'|
../../ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libopusdec.o)||In function `libopus_decode_close':|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c|121|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decoder_destroy'|
../../ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libopusdec.o)||In function `libopus_decode_init':|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c|87|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decoder_create'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c|91|undefined reference to `opus_strerror'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c|97|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decoder_ctl'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusdec.c|99|undefined reference to `opus_strerror'|
../../ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libopusenc.o)||In function `libopus_encode':|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|346|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encode'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|342|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encode_float'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|351|undefined reference to `opus_strerror'|
../../ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libopusenc.o)||In function `libopus_encode_close':|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|389|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_destroy'|
../../ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libopusenc.o)||In function `libopus_encode_init':|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|254|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_create'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|260|undefined reference to `opus_strerror'|
../../ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libopusenc.o)||In function `libopus_configure_encoder':|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|117|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|119|undefined reference to `opus_strerror'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|124|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|127|undefined reference to `opus_strerror'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|130|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|132|undefined reference to `opus_strerror'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|135|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|138|undefined reference to `opus_strerror'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|141|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|144|undefined reference to `opus_strerror'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|149|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|152|undefined reference to `opus_strerror'|
../../ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(libopusenc.o)||In function `libopus_encode_init':|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|288|undefined reference to `opus_multistream_encoder_ctl'|
/home/yonghao/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopusenc.c|290|undefined reference to `opus_strerror'|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|
```

Here are my screen shot of the CodeBlock linker setting.

```
ffmpeg_build/lib/libvpx.a
ffmpeg_build/lib/libswscale.a
ffmpeg_build/lib/libwresample.a
ffmpeg_build/lib/libpostproc.a
ffmpeg_build/lib/libfdk-aac.a
ffmpeg_build/lib/libvutil.a
ffmpeg_build/lib/libvformat.a
ffmpeg_build/lib/libavfilter.a
ffmpeg_build/lib/libavdevice.a
ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a
```

Totally 10 libs.

My Questions:

1. Are these errors caused by lacking libs or libs not linked.
2. What libs I missing or what libs should I add to linker.

Comment: in one word: YES. e.g.: `libmp3lame.c` -> `lame`.

Comment: link the missing libraries.

Comment: ya, thank you i have fixed by adding -lmp3lame

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be linking order mismatched. To understand linking order please refer
[Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Try the following linking order

```
libavdevice
libavformat
libavfilter
libavcodec
libwscale
libavutil
libswresample
libswscale
libpostproc
libavresample
```